# JSONPath for matching child value

Tags: jsonpath

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to write a json path which fits my needs, without success.
I hope someone will be able to help me.

I've got a very simple JSON object that looks like: `{"code":..., "message":...}`, note that this is not a list of objects

I'm trying to find a JSON path that returns [%code%] when code > 100, else [].

I've found `$[?(@.code > 100)].code` which works fine with Jayway & Gatling implementations, but doesn't with Nebahle and Goessner implementations (according to http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/).

Sadly the project I'm working on is using a jsonpath lib with Goessner implementation.
Does anyone have an idea of a jsonpath that could work for any implementation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no agreement between different JSONPath implementations for applying a filter expression to a JSON object. Some apply it to the object itself (e.g. Jayway), some apply it to each value of the JSON object (e.g. Goessner Javascript), and some don't seem to support it at all (e.g. Goessner PHP). Christoph Burgmer's JSONPath comparisons reports these differences [here](https://cburgmer.github.io/json-path-comparison/results/filter_expression_on_object.html).

In your case, assuming Goessner Javascript, you might be able to get away with

```
$[?(@>100)]                               (1)
```

or perhaps safer

```
$[?(typeof(@) == 'number' && @ > 100)]    (2)
```

For example, given `{"code":101, "message":"101"}`, (1) produces

```
[101,"101"]
```

while (2) produces

```
[101]
```

(according to http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: thanks for the solution Daniel, I'll use it


(2) is safer but not perfect as it's not based on the field name, we could imagine another field than code that as an integer value greater than 100, the jsonpath would then be wrong


thanks again!